# Search engine code error

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

I am hoping to get some help with my search engine, I am trying to write 
so far I have two `.php` files one is `index.php` and the other is `search.php`. `index.php` is a front end website where the users enters what it is they want to search for and search is where the results should be shown. However I don't think my code is working and I get a lot of the code I have written underneath the search bar when attempting to perform a search.

here are the codes:
index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C??DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" http://www.w3.org/TR/xxhtmll/DTD/xhtmll-transitional.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-eqiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title> Trial Report Database - Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
    <h2>CIS TDU Trial Report</h2>
    <form action='./search.php' method='get'>
    <input type='text' name='k' size='100' />
    <input type='submit' value='Search'>
    </form>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

and search.php

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" http://www.w3.org/TR/xxhtmll/DTD/xhtmll-transitional.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-eqiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title> Trial Report Database - Search</title>
</head>
<body>

    <center>
    <h2>CIS TDU Trial Report</h2>

    <form action='./search.php' method='get'>
        <input type='text' name='k' size='100' placeholder='Enter Trial Here...' />
        <input type='submit' value='Search' /> 
    </form>
    </center>

    <hr />
    <?php
        $k = $_GET['k'];
        $terms = explode("", $k);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM cistdutrd WHERE keywords='$term1'" 

        foreach ($terms as $each){
            $i++;

            if ($i == 1)            
                $query .= "keywords LIKE '%$each%'";
            else 
                $query .= "OR keywords LIKE '%$each%'";
    }

    echo $query

    //collect
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password");
    mysql_select_db("cistdutrd");

    $query = mysql_query($query);
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if ($numrows > 0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            $id = $row['id'];
            $TName = $row['Trial Name'];
            $TType = $row['Trial Type'];
            $TTeam = $row['Trial Team'];
            $Date = $row['Date'];
            $RHyperlink = $row['Report Hyperlink'];

            echo "<h2><a href='$link'>$TName<a/></h2>
            $TType<br /><br />";
        }

    }
    else

    echo "No results found for \"<b>$k</b>\"";

    //disconnect
    mysql_close ();

    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help as to why this isn't working. It would be greatly appreciated. 
many thanks 
tim

Comment: Lot of bugs in your code. You should learn some more first from some tutorials sites. e.g. http://www.w3schools.com/ ,  http://www.tizag.com/phpT/

Comment: would you mind going through it with me please?

Comment: first very basic thing, why two tags of html are there on each page

Comment: seen that mistake iv changed it

Comment: you should use if(isset($_GET['k])) condition in search.php file and check database connection where are you creating this.  Please check tutorials site before making any work ahead.

Comment: Files should be on server and check tutorial of DB connection. In your case you are try to run query earlier than DB connection. It is very basic thing. Better to learn more first. Good Luck.